# Lectura y escritura de ficheros

Tags: c, fgets

```
FILE *salida,*entrada;
char *nombreA[20]*, *linea[20]*;
int *calculo(int num)*;
int main(){
  int pid, num;

  // Se solicitan numeros al usuario
  printf("\nProceso padre solicitando datos de entrada\n");
  printf("Escribe un numero: ");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  // Creacion del proceso hijo
  pid = fork();

if (pid != 0){
  // El proceso padre espera a que concluya el proceso hijo
  waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

  // Inauguracion del archivo de entrada
  memset(nombreA, '\0', sizeof(nombreA));
  // Se genera el nombre del archivo con el PID del proceso hijo
  sprintf(nombreA, "PID%d",pid);
  // Creacion del archivo de salida
  entrada = fopen(nombreA, "r");

  if (entrada == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error al abrir el archivo %s\n", nombreA);
    return 0;
  }

  // Se lee la primra linea del archivo, se almacena en la variable linea y se imprime
  fgets(linea, sizeof(linea), entrada);
  printf("Proceso padre imprimiendo resultados\n");
  // COMPARA SI ES PALINDROMO
  fgets(linea, sizeof(linea), entrada);
  if (atoi(linea) == 1){
    printf("Es palindromo\n");
  } else {
    printf("No es palindromo\n");
  }
  //TERMINA COMPARACION

  // Clausura del archivo de entrada
  fclose(entrada);
  return 1;
} else {
  // Creacion del archivo
  memset(nombreA, '\0', sizeof(nombreA));
  // Generacion del nombre del archivo
  sprintf(nombreA, "PID%d", getpid());
  // Creacion del archivo de salida
  salida = fopen(nombreA, "w");
  if (salida = NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error al crear el archivo %s\n", nombreA);
    return 0;
  }

  //CALCULO PALINDROMO
  calculo(num);
  //TERMINA CALCULO PALINDROMO

  // Se informa al user el nombre del file
  printf("\nProceso hijo: El resultado fue almacenado en el archivo con nombre %s\n", nombreA);

  // Se cierra el archivo
  fclose(salida);
  return 1;
}
}

int calculo(int num){
  char L[20];
  int sino, aux, largo, mitad, i, C[20], firstD, n = 0;
  /*Conversion int a string para leer largo de la cifra*/
  sprintf(L, "%d", num);
  /*Lee el numero de digitos de la cifra*/
  largo = strlen(L);
  /*Mitad*/
  mitad = largo / 2;

  /* Separa el numero en cifras para conocer la primera cifra*/
  aux = num;
  while (aux>0) {
    C[n] = aux % 10;
    aux = aux / 10;
    n++;
  }
  firstD = C[largo - 1];

  /*Comprueba si es palindromo*/
  for (i = 0; i<=mitad; i++){
    if(firstD != C[0]) {
      sino = 0;
    } else {
      sino = 1;
    }
  }
  //TERMINA CALCULO PALINDROMO
  // Se escribe el resultado en el archivo
  sprintf(linea, "%d", sino);
printf("Linea %s\n", linea);
  fputs(linea, salida);
}
```

Tengo este código donde al momento de querer escribir la variable *sino* para enviarla al archivo padre, este no recibe nada
Por ejemplo, *sino* toma el valor de 1 pero no se escribe nada en el archivo, y por lo tanto llega *null* al padre
¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa y cómo podría solucionarlo?

Lenguaje: c
El programa calcula si un número es palíndromo o no en el proceso hijo y cuando termina envía el resultado al padre para que lo imprima
Las librerías incluídas son (No me deja ponerlas en el código) **unistd, stdlib, string, stdio, sys/wait, sys/types**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
 salida = fopen(nombreA, "w");
  if (salida = NULL) {
```

Está asignando `NULL` a `salida`.
Lo que tienes que hacer es comparar:

```
  if (salida == NULL) {
```

Comment: Oop, gracias!! Ya funciona